# ILM Policy is rolling over later than configured

Tags: logging, logstash, rollover

I have created the following ILM Policy for testing:

```
{
  "test-1-m": {
    "version": 6,
    "modified_date": "2022-12-07T11:27:55.648Z",
    "policy": {
      "phases": {
        "hot": {
          "min_age": "0ms",
          "actions": {
            "rollover": {
              "max_primary_shard_size": "10mb",
              "max_age": "1m"
            }
          }
        },
        "delete": {
          "min_age": "1m",
          "actions": {
            "delete": {
              "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "in_use_by": {
      "indices": [
        "monitoring-logstash-alias-000008",
        "monitoring-logstash-alias-000009",
        "monitoring-logstash-alias-000010"
      ],
      "data_streams": [],
      "composable_templates": [
        "monitoring-logstash-alias"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The shard is rolled over but after 10 minutes instead of 1 as configured.
The 10 MB threshold is not applied at all.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your cluster's `indices.lifecycle.poll_interval` setting,
it affect the overall rollover policy of your cluster

Use the following command in dev tools to determine your cluster's current value:

```
GET _cluster/settings
```

This command will allow you to change the current value to your desired value:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "transient": {
         "indices.lifecycle.poll_interval": "5s"
    }
}
```